# Node.js + express - retrieving server-side data at the client

Tags: node.js, express

New to Node.js and am slowly piecing things together from a number of tutorials and other posts here on the site.

Presently, I am attempting to make an API request by means of the https module, and use a value returned (an authentication token) in the client for a lightweight example.

My current attempt is very simple - a client-side js function is called on a button press, which makes an Ajax call to a node server router.

The problem that I am having is that I cannot seem to retrieve data from the server at the client. This may be an issue of event-handling or some asynchronous behavior that I'm not fully understanding - the value I'm trying to retrieve can be seen in the `login()` function that I call. Specifically, I see this token in the `data` value that I am writing out to the console (see `api.js`)  Does anything from my current approach stand out as glaringly wrong?

Thank you in advance for any help you might be able to offer.

For context, App.js is where I am storing this route, as well as starting the server. I am then making use of the api.js module by means of an ajax call from client.js.

[image: project layout]

```
//app.js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var api = require('./public/api.js');

app.post('/login', function(req, res) {
    //token has no value currently, but along the lines of what I'm hoping to accomplish
    var token = api.login();        
    res.end(token);
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

var server = app.listen(9001, function() {
    console.log('Listening on port 9001');
});
```

```
//api.js (node module)
var exports = module.exports = {};
var querystring = require('querystring');
var https = require('https');

var host = 'api.robinhood.com';
var username = '[username here]';
var password = '[password here]';
var response = null;

function performRequest(endpoint, method, data, success) {
  var dataString = JSON.stringify(data);
  var headers = {};

  if (method == 'GET') {
    endpoint += '?' + querystring.stringify(data);
  }
  else {
    headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Content-Length': dataString.length
    };
  }
  var options = {
    host: host,
    path: endpoint,
    method: method,
    headers: headers
  };

  var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
    res.setEncoding('utf-8');

    var responseString = '';

    res.on('data', function(data) {
      responseString += data;
    });

    res.on('end', function() {
      var responseObject = JSON.parse(responseString);
      success(responseObject);
    });
  });

  req.write(dataString);
  req.end();
}

exports.login = function() {
  return performRequest('/api-token-auth/', 'POST', {
    username: username,
    password: password
  }, function(data) {
    sessionId = data.token;
    console.log('Logged in:', sessionId);
  });
}
```

```
<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="client.js"></script>
<head>
    <title>Making API Calls!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="login">Log in</button>
    <hidden id="token">Put an authentication token here</hidden>
</body>
</html>
```

```
//client.js
$(function(){
    $('#login').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:9001/login',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            datatype: 'json',
            success: function(result) {
                console.log(result); // this is where I would consume/store the token
                $('#login').html(':)');
            },
            error: function(result) {
                console.log(status);
                console.log(result);
            }
        });   
    });
});
```

Comment: Maybe you can try res.send() instead of end(). From the express docs: "Use to quickly end the response without any data. If you need to respond with data, instead use methods such as res.send() and res.json()."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `api.login` is not returning the token, it's returning what `performRequest` returns, `undefined`

Like you said it have something to do with the asynchronous behavior of login, it needs to return the token through a promise or a callback

example with a promise:

```
exports.login = function() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
      performRequest('/api-token-auth/', 'POST', {
        username: username,
        password: password
      }, function(data) {
        sessionId = data.token;
        console.log('Logged in:', sessionId);
        resolve(sessionId);
      });
    }
  });
}
```

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res) {
  api.login()
    .then(token => res.end(token))
    .catch(err => res.end(err));;
});
```

Comment: In the promise example, I would make the performRequestFunction to return a Promise instead of callback, and then exports.login = performRequestFunction. Why to mix callback and promises in the same code?

Comment: Thank you for your help!